# Connecting NiFi to Vertica

Tags: apache-nifi, vertica

I'm trying to upload a CSV file grabbed from a SFTP server to Vertica as a new table. I got the `GetSFTP` processor configured - but I can't seem to understand how do I set up the connection with Vertica and execute the SQL?

Comment: invoke the loader command via `ExecuteStreamCommand`, where loader is `vsql` or any other client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1** - You need to setup a  **DBCPConnectionPool** with your Vertica JAR(s) like @mattyb mentioned.

**2** - Create a Staging Area where you will have your Executable(copy Scripts)

**3** - Create a template to manage your Scripts or loads(ReplaceText Processor)

**Note:**

- the parameters you see here come in the flow file from upstream proccesors.
- this is reusable process group so there are many other PG`s that will have their output sent to this.

**Example:**

- data_feed task will run a Start Data Feed  (this PG will hold it`s own parameters and values) - if is executing with no error comes to this step, is it fail it goes to another reusable PG that handles Errors.
- daily ingest process (Trickle load every 5 min), - a PG will prepare the CSV file, move it to staging, makes sure is all in the right format,- if is executing with no error comes to this step, is it fail it goes to another reusable PG that handles Errors.

And so on many PG`s will use this a Reusable PG to load Data in the DB

**PG - Stand for Process Group**

- this is how mine looks

> ./home/dbadmin/.profile /opt/vertica/bin/vsql -U $username -w
>   $password -d analytics -c " copy ${TableSchema}.${TableToLoad} FROM
>   '${folder}/*.csv' delimiter '|' enclosed by '~'  null as ' ' STREAM
>   NAME '${TableToLoad} ${TaskType}' REJECTED DATA AS TABLE
>   ${TableSchema}.${TableToLoad}_Rejects; select
>   analyze_statistics('${TableSchema}.${TableToLoad}');"

-you can add you param as well or create new once

**4** - Update Attribute Proc so you can name the executable.

**5** - Putfile proc that will place the Vertica Load Script on the machine.

**6** - ExecuteStreamComnand - this will run the shell script.
- audit logs and any other stuff can be done here.

**Even Better** - see the attached Template with of a reusable PG i use for me data loads into Vertica with NIFI.

http://www.aodba.com/bulk-load-data-vertica-apache-nifi/

As for the Vertica DBCP the setup should look like this:

- where the red mark is you **ipaddress:port/dbadmin**

[image]

**Note:**
This DBCPConnectionPool can be at the project level (inside a PG) or a the NIFI level (create it in the main canvas using the Controller Services Menu)

Comment: where do I provide the values to the variables in ReplaceText?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the bulk loader idea from @sKwa , you can also create a DBCPConnectionPool with your Vertica JAR(s) and a PutSQL processor that will execute the SQL. If you need to convert from data to SQL you can use ConvertJSONToSQL, otherwise use PutDatabaseRecord which is basically a "ConvertXToSQL -> PutSQL" together.

Comment: is in the Controller Services